# Eclipse plugin: Make tab blink on event?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have an eclipse-based application with several plugins which are visible in a tabbed environment.  What I'd like to do is, on a particular event which occurs within one of those plugins, make that plugin's tab blink (or change to another color, or some other status indicator) in the UI.

Seems like it should be at least somewhat trivial, but The Google isn't being much help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean the tab of a view, then you can use `getProgressService().warnOfContentChange();` in the `ViewPart` to get the tab to be highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest approach would be to just be to to update the `ViewPart`'s icon via `setTitleImage(Image)`. If you want to animate it I can recommend the [Trident](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home) library.

If you want something more (like altering background colour) I think you will need to look at creating your own PresentationFactory that gives you access to the controls that paint the tabs. You can do this from the extention point `org.eclipse.ui.presentationFactories`, providing a class that extends AbstractPresentationFactory

```
<extension point= "org.eclipse.ui.presentationFactories" >
    <factory class="my.PresentationFactory" id="my.PresentationFactory" name="Custom Presentation" />
</extension>
```

Which you can set as the default presentation from your app's .ini file:

```
org.eclipse.ui/presentationFactoryId=my.PresentationFactory
```

Have a look at the `WorkbenchPresentationFactoryClassic` to get an idea of what goes on.

Comment: Wish I could accept two answers, as this is also an excellent method, and more flexible than the accepted one.

Comment: Well, I've just learnt something new - that other method is definitely the 'right' way of doing it. If I'd known that, I wouldn't have posted all that stuff above :)